# SSRS Report Action - To to URL - Specify file URL

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

This is a long shot, but is it possible to specify a file in the URL when configuring an Action. From my testing, it seems the answer is no. There are no errors but the file is not opened. I imagine it is some security concern. eg **file://C:/file.txt**

[image: Action Properties Dialog]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What I did before is upload the file on the report server then use Action

```
="javascript:void(window.open('"_______".txt', '_blank'))"
```